# C winsock client browser url

Tags: c, http

I am trying to learn winsock in C by making a very simple http webserver. At the moment I can serve a single webpage. I would like to implement a filesystem based on the url in the browser. How do I get the url requested by the client??

```
   // socketprogramming4.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

bool send_all(int socket, void *buffer, size_t length)
{
    char *ptr = (char*)buffer;
    while (length > 0)
    {
        int i = send(socket, ptr, length, 0);
        if (i < 1) return false;
        ptr += i;
        length -= i;
    }
    shutdown(socket, 1);

    return true;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s, new_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    int c;
    char *message, server_reply[2000];
    int recv_size;

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");
    //Create a socket

    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    printf("Socket created.\n");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(80);

    //Bind
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Bind failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    puts("Bind done");

    //Listen to incoming connections
    listen(s, 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");

    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    while ((new_socket = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &c)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        message = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel='stylesheet' href='index.css' /></head><body>Testing</body></html>";
        send_all(new_socket, message, strlen(message));
    }

    if (new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("accept failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The client sends you data but you're not reading any of it.  I'd start there.  https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html

Comment: I know the client sends me data but I don't know how to read the data in C.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I tried that in my while loop it doesn't receive anything. But I'm probably not using it right I can get the ip of the client with client.sin_addr

Comment: You're a star that's exactly what it was thanks so much. I was using recv wrong and not getting anything back as a result.

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? __Always__ check for errors returned by system funcs...e.g. [socket errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580(v=vs.85).aspx). As for going 1 step further and making your server asynch, use [select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx) or [poll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741669(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I am getting an error about not setting the Mime Type for the css stylesheet that isn't linked to in chrome. I'm hoping implementing a filesystem will allow me to load stylesheets, javascript and images but it mightn't be that easy. No errors in visual studio though and recv is returning the headers fine now.

Comment: Is  _Chrome_ (or any web browser) willing to connect to a **non secured** server (as in your case), without complaining about anything?

Comment: All the browsers work but there is mime type errors and I haven't tried forms or xmlhttp requests http://i.imgur.com/Ckkgyzy.png